# BDD Should I repeat givens and outcomes in consecutive scenarios

Tags: bdd, specflow

Given a scenario that tests sending a message to a 3rd-party API, I can repeat certain givens, and also givens with related outcomes, to each scenario in the feature. This makes each scenario quite complex.

If I don't do that, then there are basically hidden assumptions. My question is if, in practice, these hidden assumptions cause problems, and also if they are generally understood by stakeholders to be given even if not explicitly stated.

Any strategies to lessen the risks are very welcome. I thought that leading out with one or more scenarios that cover 'general' givens and 'general' givens + outcomes, should work as clarification that, for the scenarios that follow, you can disregard those requirement and consider them covered. My doubt is that this is still an assumption.

Example scenario with 2 'general' givens, and 2 'general' givens with related outcomes:

```
Scenario 1: An eligible order
    Given an order that has been placed yesterday
    And that has a value > 100
    And that has an order ID equal to 42
    And that has an affiliate reference equal to foo
    When the conversion for the order is sent
    Then the conversion has an ID equal to 42
    And the conversion has an affiliate ID equal to foo
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach has been to have a verbose example at the top of the feature file, say:

```
Scenario 1: An eligible order
    Given an order that has been placed yesterday
    And that has a value > 100
    And that has an order ID equal to 42
    And that has an affiliate reference equal to foo
    When the conversion for the order is sent
    Then the conversion has an ID equal to 42
    And the conversion has an affiliate ID equal to foo
```

Then less verbose ones further down:

```
Scenario x: An eligible order does something
    Given an applicable order
    ...
```

With the **Given an applicable order** step simply calling the 4 original steps in sequence.

This gives cleaner follow on features, but makes the tests still have the same specific steps called "under the hood".

The first scenario would define the eligible orders for this feature file, and the subsequent ones would make use of them.

Comment: I like the idea of summarizing those steps into a new given. Thanks!